# Can't get DropdownListFor to work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, dropdownlistfor

I've been trying to get DropDownListFor working in ASP.NET MVC using values from another table to link the model to the option selected. Full disclosure, I have very little idea what I'm doing and just working off examples.

Creating the DropDownList as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenreId, (SelectList)ViewBag.GenreSelect, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

GenreId is a column in the model's table.

I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type
>   'IEnumerable' that has the key 'GenreId'

ViewBag set like this before going to the view: (Id and name are columns in the Genre table)

```
private void SetGenreViewBag(int? GenreId= null)
    {
        if (GenreId== null)

            ViewBag.GenreSelect= new SelectList(db.Genres, "Id", "name");

        else

            ViewBag.GenreSelect = new SelectList(db.Genres, "Id", "name", GenreId);

    }
```

The model has a column for the Id of the genre.

I think my main problem is I don't understand the syntax of the DropDownListFor function, plus there's a dozen different overloads for it so it's hard to decipher. What is the purpose of the first parameter with the lambda? It seems to be taking the value you specify from the select list  values, but I don't get how this connects to the model. Haven't found a clear answer online.

I thought I had this working, but something I did made it stop working. I also had it working before that with DropDownList() but I saw that DropDownListFor would be a bit better plus I couldn't get the HTML attributes working properly in DropDownList().

Thank you!

EDIT: Inside controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        SetGenreViewBag();
        return View();
    }
```

NOTE: The dropdown list shows all the right items (i.e. genres) but it crashes when I save the form.

```
// POST: Home/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Song songToCreate)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Songs.Add(songToCreate);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Song model:

```
namespace MyModule.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Song
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int genreId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does SetGenreViewBag get called?

Comment: Inside the Create() method in the controller. Updated the question to include this.

Comment: Please add the code of `Create` method with [HttpPost] attribute.

Comment: OK, added the code in the other create method

Comment: Does the data saved to the database successfully when you save the form?

Comment: No, it crashes on the line with the DropDownListFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have this syntax

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenreId, (SelectList)ViewBag.GenreSelect, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The first parameter indicates which property of the model will be assigned the selected value of the dropdown, which is `GenreId` in this case. I don't see anything wrong with the way you generate the dropdown, but since you get the error when you save the form, I think the problem is inside the `Create` method with `[HttpPost]` attribute below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Song songToCreate)
{
    try
    {
        db.Songs.Add(songToCreate);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I would guess that an error happens for some reason inside the `try` block, then the code in the `catch` block is executed and it returns to the same page but `ViewBag.GenreSelect` is already gone so you get the `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'GenreId'` error. Try to add `SetGenreViewBag()` inside the `catch` block so `ViewBag.GenreSelect` will be repopulated. Also add `(Exception ex)` to the `catch` block to find out the error inside the `try` block

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Song songToCreate)
{
    try
    {
        db.Songs.Add(songToCreate);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SetGenreViewBag();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so now instead of crashing it just reloads the page and doesn't save anything. Doesn't address the underlying issue, which has to do with how I'm creating the ViewBag select list and/or the DropDownListFor line (which is where the crash occurs).

Comment: How you create the `ViewBag` and use `DropDownListFor` is fine, the error is because you didn't repopulate `ViewBag.GenreSelect` when returning to the same page after saving the form.

Comment: The form does not save.

Comment: Now we need to find out the error that happens inside the `try` block. Change the `catch` block to `catch (Exception ex)`, then debug and see what the value of `ex.Message` is.

Comment: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: Can you add the code of `Song` class and also the value of all `songToCreate` properties when `Create` HttpPost method is executed?

Comment: Added the song class. Not sure what you mean by the value of all songToCreate properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64955/discussion-between-ekad-and-shim).